# Dynamic start-up circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Many circuits have two possible states: one state is that in which every current and voltage is zero, the other state is the "correct" state. In order to avoid the trivial state and force the circuit in the correct state, a start-up circuit is required. This circuit injects a current in a transistor in order to force a current to flow. Let's consider the following dynamic start-up circuit:

[image]

M4 is the diode-connected transistor of a current mirror belonging to the circuit that we want to "activate" (i.e. avoid the trivial state). When the circuit is turned on, Vdd goes from zero to its value ideally like a step. Assuming Cs initially discharged, node B will remain at zero for a while (and thus transistor MS1 is on, producing a glitch of current which "activates" M4) and then will raise to Vdd exponentially (causing MS1 to gradually turn off, which is correct since M4 has already been activated).

The author of my book says:

**"The dynamic start-up circuit doesn’t monitor the reference current but simply
produces a glitch current in M4 that, hopefully, will bring the circuit in the
desired operative point. Therefore, the circuit works properly only if the off-to-on time of the supply voltage is pretty fast, compared to the time constant Rs*Cs. In addition to this, the parasitic capacitance from node B and Vdd should be small compared to the capacitor Cs. If not the coupling of node B with the Vdd line attenuates the glitch at the gate to source of MS1 eventually preventing
it to exceed the threshold."**

What does it mean? The author says that if some conditions (which I don't understand) are not satisfied, then the start-up circuit will not work. But actually it seems to me that the circuit should always work: indeed, if the capacitor is initially discharged, node B must go from zero to Vdd exponentially, thus necessarily turning on (and then, as node B raises, turning off) MS1, which "activates" M4.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the Vdd is brought up from 0V to nominal operating voltage very slowly relative to the RC time constant of Rs*Cs so that node B is essentially at Vdd potential at all times. MS1 could then never turn on.

So this is possibly an unreliable start-up circuit because it depends on rapid application of Vdd.

Keep in mind that on-chip resistors are probably (and preferably) relatively low resistance and on-chip capacitors are usually tens of pF or (preferably) less. For example, 100k and 10pF would have a time constant of only 1\$\mu\$s.

Comment: Maybe I have understood: if Vdd changes too slowly, then it's true that, assuming the capacitor initially discharged, node B will be at zero V, but all transistors are for sure off (because Vdd starts raising from zero and Vdd is the supply). Thus if Vdd raises slowly then node B tracks Vdd. As a consequence, when Vdd reaches its final value (and thus all transistor should be on), also node B will be already very high and transistor MS1 will never turn on. Is it correct?